# balls and boxes; permutation and combination.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $2010$ boxes labeled $B_1, B_2, . . . . B_{2010}$ and $2010n $ balls have been distributed among them, for some positive integer $n$. You may redistribute the balls by a sequence of moves; each of which consists of choosing an $i$ and
>   moving exactly $i$ balls from box $B_i$ into any one other box.
>
> For which values of $n$ is it possible to reach the distribution with exactly $n$ balls in each box, regardless of the initial distribution of balls?

I'm unable to completely understand the question. There are (2010n)C(2010) ways of choosing the balls to keep them in each of the boxes. If the balls are identical, the permutation is not held into account. So, if we initially put n balls in each of the 2010 boxes, then the total number of balls used is 2010n.  So, isn't it that for every value of n, there's 1 possibility that each box contains n number of balls? However, I'm unable to find out how many moves are needed when there is unequal distribution of balls as it happens in rest of the (2010n)C2010 - 1 cases.

Comment: Please provide context for the query, and tell us what you've managed or where you are confused. You are, after all, asking for help, not assigning homework.

Comment: Look carefully at the question; this isn't about counting how many ways you can do something. Instead, it's asking about redistributing. For example, suppose that $n=1$. You have 2010 balls distributed among the boxes. If they are all in $B_1$, then you can redistribute them by picking $1$ ball from box $B_1$ and putting it in $B_2$; then take $1$ ball from box $B_1$ and putting it in $B_3$, and so on, until you have exactly one ball in each box. If you have $1010$ balls in $B_{2010}$ and $1000$ balls in $B_{2009}$, though, you can't do the redistribution because there is no legal move.

Comment: (Because to move balls out of $B_{2010}$, you need to be able to pick up $2010$ balls and move them elsewhere, and there aren't enough balls; and to move balls out of $B_{2009}$ you need to be able to pick up $2009$, and there aren't enough balls. So for $n=1$, there are ways of putting the balls into the boxes initially so that you cannot redistribute them through legal moves to end up with an equal distribution. The question is for which values of $n$ can you *always* redistribute them to end up with an equal distribution, regardless of how they are placed at first?

Comment: Note: This is Putnam 2010 B3.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, for n=1, I'm getting 2010 ways of redistribution (considering $B_1$ contains 2010 balls, then $B_1$ contains 2009 balls and $B_2$ contains 1 ball and so on). How do I account for the rest?

Comment: @Tap: You are not answering the correct question. **This is not about counting**. So if you are counting things, then you are doing it wrong.